# When you create a custom token (asset) on Stellar do you receive the Lumens (XLM) in your wallet for each one sold?

Tags: assets, xlm, token, stellar-laboratory, token-wallet

When you create a custom token (asset) on Stellar and request that 10,000, for example, be made available, do these all simply appear without cost to you (minus nominal account costs of a few Lumens) and do you then receive the Lumens (XLM) in your wallet for the tokens when first sold?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but being new to the concept and having read the FAQs and guides, I can't isolate an answer to this simple question and want to establish whether it is a viable approach for the project I have in mind before proceeding.

Edit: Having now been through the tutorial and having created a test Token/Asset, I'm still not clear when I send the "Payment" from the Issuing Account to the Distribution Account whether there is a cost here relative to the value and the volume of the token being transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, the issuer account can mint unlimited new custom tokens by just transacting a regular payment operation without any further costs (except the regular ~0.00001 XLM per transaction fee as for any other transaction). In case you want to have a limited supply, you can mint all tokens at once and permanently lock the issuer account afterwards to make clear that no more new tokens can be minted in future.

Your custom tokens can be sold by creating an offer and as soon as this offer is fulfilled the other party will get your tokens in their account and you will get whatever you requested in your offer (be it native XLM or any other token on the stellar network) into your account.

Comment: Thank you, I've started playing with the testnet and the fog is starting to lift.